# Firebase Writing with Security Rules

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, firebase

I have a Node app with a Firebase db with security like this :

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        "albums": {
            ".write": "auth != null",
        }
    }
}
```

I login like this:

```
var firebaseTokenGenerator = require('firebase-token-generator'),
    firebase = require('firebase');

var tokenGenerator = new firebaseTokenGenerator('my key');
var token = tokenGenerator.createToken();

var albumRef = new firebase('https://glowing-fire-8113.firebaseio.com/albums');

albumRef.auth(token, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log("Authentication failed!");
    } else {
        console.log("Login succeeded!");
    }
});
```

I get "Login succeeded!" printed to the console.

Then, later on I call this function:

```
var addAlbum = function(album, callback) {
    if(album["album"] && album["artist"] && album["image"]) {
        albumRef.push().set(album);
        callback(null);
    }
    callback(new Error("Album JSON was missing some items"));
};
```

But, I get this printed out:

```
FIREBASE WARNING: set at /albums/-JMU95j8W4Vz3kchhNzL failed: permission_denied
```

What is going on here? Am I doing authentication incorrectly?

For reference, I'm using

```
"firebase" : "1.0.14",
"firebase-token-generator" : "0.1.4",
```

Comment: You haven't put any data into the token. Try putting a user id or something into it, so there is something to reference as the auth object in security rules?